# I removed the video download button but it only works for the first post

Tags: html, django, google-chrome, web, video

**I have no idea where the problem comes from, a similar problem happens with the like button.**
**I've left my code below, if you want I can post it in more detail**
{% for post_item in post_items %} doesn't seem to work as it should, but whyyyy?

my.html

```
    {% for post_item in post_items %}
    <ul style="padding-inline-start: 10px;" id="dataList_post">
      <li class="content hidden">
      <div>            

        <div class="post" style="min-height: 174px; border: 1px solid #f0f0f0; border-width: 2px; border-radius: 20px; max-width: 600px; height: auto; margin-right: 100px;">
            <div class="posticon">
                {% if post_item.user.profile.avatar %}
                <a style="text-decoration: none; color: black;" href="{% url 'users' post_item.user %}"><img src="{{ post_item.user.profile.avatar.url }}" style="border-radius: 100%; width: 48px; height: 48px;" alt=""></a>
                {% else %}
                <a style="text-decoration: none; color: black;" href="{% url 'users' post_item.user %}"><img src="{% static 'img/default.png' %}" style="border-radius: 100%; width: 48px; height: 48px;"  alt=""></a>
                {% endif %}                 
            </div>
            <div class="postname">
              <a style="text-decoration: none; color: black;" href="{% url 'users' post_item.user %}">
                <h5 class="postname_location" style="font-family: cursive;"><b>{{ post_item.user.username }}</b></h5>
              </a>
            </div>
            
            <div class="postcomment">
              <a style="text-decoration: none; color:black;" href="{{ post_item.get_absolute_url }}">
                <span>{{ post_item.caption }}</span>
                <br>
                </a>
              {% for tag in post_item.tags.all %}<a href="{{ tag.get_absolute_url }}"><b>#{{ tag }}</b></a>{% endfor %} 
              <small class="font-italic text-muted" style="float: right;">{{ post_item.posted | naturaltime }}</small>
            </div>

          {% if post_item.content.first.file.name|slice:"-3:" == 'jpg' or post_item.content.first.file.name|slice:"-3:" == 'png' %}
            
              <div class="dropdown_post">
                <a data-toggle="dropdown"><img style="max-height: 560px; max-width: 560px;min-width:560px;  border-radius: 10px;"  src="{{ post_item.content.first.file.url }}" alt="Placeholder image"></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-content_notf dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-center_img">            
                    <img style="max-height: 900px; max-width: 1200px;"  src="{{ post_item.content.first.file.url }}" alt="Placeholder image">
                  </ul>      
                </div>  

          {% elif post_item.content.first.file.name|slice:"-3:" == 'mp4' %}

              <video class="postvideo" style="max-height: 600px;"  controls="controls" preload="metadata">
                <source src="{{ post_item.content.first.file.url }}#t=0.5" type="video/mp4">        
              </video> 

          {% else %}

          {% endif %}      
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
    </li>
    </ul>
    
    {% endfor %}
      <a style="margin-left:300px; border-radius:100px;background-image: url('img/more.png'); " class="more_post" id="moreButton_post" type="button" onclick="showMore()"><img src="{% static 'img/more.png' %}"></a>
</div>

    
      <script>
        document.querySelector('video').setAttribute("controlslist", "nodownload");
      </script>
    {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`querySelector()` returns the first item that matches

`querySelectorAll()` returns an array of all objects that match

to update the attributes on all videos, you'll want to use something like:

```
nodes = document.querySelectorAll('video')
for (var i=0; i<nodes.length; i++) {
  node = nodes[i];
  node.setAttribute("controlslist", "nodownload");
}
```

Comment: Yessss that worked. Thanks... I have one more question on my profile if you have time.